# Django Template Inheritance : How can I stop base template from reloading?

Tags: django, google-app-engine, django-templates

I have a base template in Django and several html files that are children of the base.

Is there a way I can display different HTML children without refreshing the base?

I am basically trying to prevent the base HTML reload and blink every time a new page is displayed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cant just "refresh the children", because django processing is server-side, not client-side.

You can make that "effect" using Javascript with AJAX (recommend JQuery).